# What does integer ''3'' specify in following line of code: tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<3>

Tags: tensorflow, arduino

I'm kinda new to tensorflow/keras, and I'm deploying my neural network on arduino, and I I've looked everywhere on the internet, and could not find what the following integer does (specifies):

```
  static tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver**<3>** micro_mutable_op_resolver;
  micro_mutable_op_resolver.AddFullyConnected();//
  micro_mutable_op_resolver.AddLogistic();//
  micro_mutable_op_resolver.AddRelu();
```

If I put 0,1,2 into this statement, my code does not work properly, only works, when numbers are 3 or larger..

Thank you for your help in advance!
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

It is a template parameter specifying the maximum number of ops you can register with the `tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver` object.

You followed that line with three `*.Add` function calls (i.e. registering three operations), therefore you need the resolver to have a capacity of at least 3.

TensorFlow is open source, so you can always look to the code for answers. Check the header file [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.5/tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h). Take note of the class definition:

```cpp
template <unsigned int tOpCount>
class MicroMutableOpResolver : public MicroOpResolver {
...
```

`tOpCount` is the value you set to `3` in your code. You can trace it though the header if you want to see details of how it is used.

If template parameters are new to you (from the question it seems you are fairly new to C++ as well), you can get all the details you need on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) (your case is a "Non-type template parameter"). Any decent C++ tutorial should also cover the topic in a more newbie-friendly manner.